# Visual Studio 2017 and Windows App Certification Kit: test errors

Tags: windows, uwp, app-certification-kit

I'm trying to publish my app on the `Microsoft Store`. When I run the `Windows App Certification Kit` I receive for each action an error related with `Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase`.

I'm using `Visual Studio 2017` Version 15.9.3

[image: Visual Studio About]

> Bytecode generation
>   Error Found: The bytecode generation test detected the following errors:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.Utility.IsPackageWWA(AppXPackage package) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Tests.BytecodeGenerationCheck.BytecodeGenerationCheck.ExecuteSharedValidation(String manifestFilePath, String packageFullName) at Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.TestBase.TestBase.ExecuteTest()
>   Impact if not fixed: As a performance optimization to accelerate JavaScript execution time, JavaScript files ending in the ".js" extension generate bytecode when the app is deployed. This optimization significantly improves start-up and ongoing execution times for JavaScript. 
>   How to fix: You may need consider one or more of these steps to fix the issue:
>   - Avoid deploying the app by pressing F5 in Visual Studio, create an app package instead
>   - Ensure that event logging is enabled
>   - All JavaScript files are syntactically valid; otherwise exclude the respective files from the package
>   - Please note that you should uninstall all previous versions of the app before deploying
>   Otherwise exclude the respective files from the package.

[image: Errors]

I verified in my Visual Studio Installer and the Windows SDK in installed.

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

Also, I checked the `targeting` version of the project:

- Target version: 1809 (10.0; Build 17763)
- Min version: November Update (10.0; Build 10586)

[image: Application Targeting]

There is not SDK for this build...

Comment: It is almost certainly app-specific and as you haven't provided any app related information it is also almost certain that you won't get the answer. This should tell you everything: As a performance optimization to accelerate JavaScript execution time, JavaScript files ending in the ".js" extension generate bytecode when the app is deployed. This optimization significantly improves start-up and ongoing execution times for JavaScript. How to fix: You may need consider one or more of these steps to fix the issue: - Avoid deploying the app by pressing F5 in Visual Studio, create an app package...

Comment: My app is in `Xamarin`. It is nothing related to `.js`

Comment: @Enrico Is it local WACK or online WACK shows this result? If it is locl WACK what about test the online WACK first?

Comment: Thank you @BarryWang-MSFT this is a local result. I uploaded yesterday my app in the submission process and I'm waiting the result. For `online WACK` do you mean to submit the app or the is another online tool?

Comment: @Enrico I just mean you can directly submit to store and see the result. Sometimes local test may return some wrong value. So actually we'd better check the result from the online submission.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT ok thank you. I'm waiting then. Do you think I can do anything to fix my local `WACK`?

Comment: @Enrico Currently I'm afraid no. I never knew that a Xamarin project will raise js error although I seems can see another user report this from MSDN forum. Also WACK is just a tool which hasn't provide us any way to modify/troubleshoot it. Personally if you can pass the online WACK I'm afraid we can only try report this from FeedBack Hub Tool on Windows 10. Maybe developers can find some dumps by using it.

Comment: I get the same issue with the WACK for a one page UWP project.  It seems like a lot of false positives.  It also says it finds errors, but then doesn't tell you what they are (it either shows a stack trace like it's having an issue or it just doesn't show the errors after same as in your screenshot).  I also have no JavaScript files in my project and stripped it to the bone.  I'm not ready to submit it online but I want to know I haven't built code off something will fail and be problematic to undo later (I'd rather fail early).

Comment: @Enrico this is a month late but I'm currently getting the same on my apps. I've googled around and I'm 90% sure there's a huge issue with the new Certification Kit, because I'm having these errors on countless apps I've made, in both VS2017 and 2013, apps that didn't have these errors previously, and they all say the same thing, `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Thank you @TKoL I still have the same issue. Now what I am doing is uploading in the portal and waiting the result. Hopefully with `Visual Studio 2019` it will work well.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT  I know this is offtopic but does anyone know where to upload the WACK XML test results to? Everything directs to the new hardware certification page and has no ability to upload results. I've googled, submitted support tickets and asked on every MS forum I can find with no answer.